# How to check on which page of a word document a shape/image is located using C# Interop

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, interop, office-interop

Using

```
var shapes = currentDocument.Shapes;
foreach (Shape shape in shapes)
    if (shape.Type == MsoShapeType.msoPicture)
    {
        InlineShapeHelper.ReplaceInlineShape(...);
        break;
    }
```

I can replace the first image in "currentDocument".

How can I detect on which page the image is located (or in this case also sufficient: if it's on the first page)?

I want to replace an specific image on the first page, so is it maybe even possible to extract the image or check otherwise if the image is the one I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your specific question: How can I detect on which page the image is located?

The `get_Information` method can return the page number of a given `Range` using the enumeration `Word.WdInformation.wdActiveEndPageNumber`.

A `Shape` is always anchored to a specific character in the document - this is the `Range` property of the Shape (`Shape.Anchor`).

The following code sample demonstrates how to loop the Shapes in a document, get their name and page number. Note that if the `Shape.Name` is known it's possible to pick up a `Shape` object directly (`Shapes["Name As String"]`). But you need to be careful with names generated by the Word application when Shape is inserted as Word can change the name it assigns itself at any time. If a name is assigned using code that name remains static - Word won't change it.

```
         Word.ShapeRange shpRange = doc.Content.ShapeRange;
        foreach (Word.Shape shp in shpRange)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(shp.Name + ", " + shp.Anchor.get_Information(Word.WdInformation.wdActiveEndPageNumber).ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way I found just after posting the question is to generate the hash-code of the image:

```
var shapes = currentDocument.Shapes;
foreach (Shape shape in shapes)
    if (shape.Type == MsoShapeType.msoPicture)
    {
        int hash = shape.GetHashCode();
        InlineShapeHelper.ReplaceInlineShape(...);
        break;
    }
```

But I would still be interested in other, better, more elegant solutions and the possibility to get to know the page number.